# Сравнить DateTime с DateTime и получить разницу C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
У меня создан класс который содержит в себе переменную id (string) и переменную date (DateTime). date будет создержать в себе дату записи значения в id. И в классе есть функция которая должна проверять то DateTime которое ей дали с DateTime.Now, если DateTime.Now болье того на 4 часа вернуть True, если же нет False.
Вот приблизительный код класса

```
public class Ids
{
    public string ID { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; protected set; }

    public Ids(string id, DateTime time)
    {
        ID = id;
        Date = time;
    }

    public bool Available()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Помогите узнать разницу между date (переменной которую подает пользователь) и DateTime.Now

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему,

```
date + TimeSpan.FromHours(4) < DateTime.Now
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool F(DateTime d) => d.AddHours(4) < DateTime.Now;
```

Ну или так (более наглядно):

```
readonly double hoursInterval = 4;
bool F(DateTime d) => (DateTime.Now - d).TotalHours > hoursInterval;
```